# Как исправить кривой икс в нав менью

Tags: javascript, css

Подскажите пожалуйста как исправить этот кривой икс.

Сначала до клика вид у него нормальный так как надо а после клика становитсья слишком страшным надо преоброзовать на нормальный икс .

И подскажите пожалуйста в каких строках что вы изменили чтобы мне понять суть.

```js
let navButton = document.querySelector(".nav-button");

navButton.addEventListener("click", (e) => { 
  e.preventDefault();
  
  // toggle nav state
  document.body.classList.toggle("nav-visible");
});
```

```css
header {
    height: 80px;
    left: 0;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: right;
    top: 0;
    transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s;
    transition: transform 0.6s;
    transition: transform 0.6s, -webkit-transform 0.6s;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 500;
  }
  
  main {
    background-color: #485274;
    height: 100vh;
    padding-top: 80px;
    -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
            transform-origin: left center;
    transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s 50ms;
    transition: transform 0.6s 50ms;
    transition: transform 0.6s 50ms, -webkit-transform 0.6s 50ms;
  }
  

  
  .nav-button {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    outline: none;
  }
  
  .nav-wrapper {
    background-color: #343c55;
    box-shadow: -1px 0px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 80px;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
            perspective: 1000px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
            transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: visibility 0.6s, -webkit-transform 0.6s;
    transition: transform 0.6s, visibility 0.6s;
    transition: transform 0.6s, visibility 0.6s, -webkit-transform 0.6s;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 25vw;
  }
  .nav-visible .nav-wrapper {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
            transform: translateX(0);
    visibility: visible;
  }
  
  .nav {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
            transform: rotateY(90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
            transform-origin: left center;
    transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s;
    transition: transform 0.6s;
    transition: transform 0.6s, -webkit-transform 0.6s;
  }
  .nav-visible .nav {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
            transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  .nav li.active a {
    background-color: #212635;
  }
  .nav a {
    display: block;
    line-height: 1.4;
    padding: 0.7em 0.5em 0.7em 1.4em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  .nav a:focus, .nav a:hover {
    background-color: #2b3145;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
  .nav-marker {
    background-color: currentColor;
    height: 2.8rem;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 80px;
    width: 3px;
  }
  .nav-marker:before {
    border: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right-color: inherit;
    content: "";
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 3px;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
            transform: translateY(-50%);
    width: 0;
  }
  
  .color-1 {
    color: deeppink;
  }
  
  .button-lines {
       margin-right: 20px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 50;
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1rem 0.5rem;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
       -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
  }
  
  .lines {
    background: #000;
    border-radius: 0.2rem;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 0.2rem;
    width: 2rem;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .lines:after {
    background: #000;
    border-radius: 0.2rem;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 0.2rem;
    width: 0.9em;
    content: "";
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
  }
  .lines:before {
    background: #000 !important;
    border-radius: 0.2rem;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 0.2rem;
    width: 2rem;
    content: "";
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
  }
  
  .lines:after {
    top: 0.5rem;
  }
  .lines:before {
    top: -0.5rem;
  }
  
  .button-lines-x .lines {
    transition: background .3s ease;
  }
  .button-lines-x .lines:after, .button-lines-x .lines:before {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50% 0;
            transform-origin: 50% 50% 0;
    transition: top .3s .4s ease, -webkit-transform .3s ease;
    transition: top .3s .4s ease, transform .3s ease;
    transition: top .3s .4s ease, transform .3s ease, -webkit-transform .3s ease;
  }
  .nav-visible .button-lines-x .lines {
    background: transparent;
  }
  .nav-visible .button-lines-x .lines:after, .nav-visible .button-lines-x .lines:before {
    top: 0;
    transition: top .3s ease, -webkit-transform .3s .3s ease;
    transition: top .3s ease, transform .3s .3s ease;
    transition: top .3s ease, transform .3s .3s ease, -webkit-transform .3s .3s ease;
  }
  .nav-visible .button-lines-x .lines:after {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 45deg);
            transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 45deg);
  }
  .nav-visible .button-lines-x .lines:before {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -45deg);
            transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -45deg);
  }
```

```html
 <header>
   <h1 class="header-title">Bulbasaur</h1>
   <button aria-label='Toggle menu' class='nav-button button-lines button-lines-x close' role='button' type='button'>
     <span class='lines'></span>
   </button>

   <nav class='nav-wrapper'>
     <ul class='nav'>
       <li class='active'>
         <a href='#'>Page 1</a>
       </li>
       <li>
         <a href='#'>Page 2</a>
       </li>
       <li>
         <a href='#'>Page 3</a>
       </li>
       <li>
         <a href='#'>Page 4</a>
       </li>
     </ul>
     <span class='nav-marker color-1'></span>
   </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: lines:after и lines:before  вот эти штуки мпнят надо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let navButton = document.querySelector(".nav-button");

navButton.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  // toggle nav state
  document.body.classList.toggle("nav-visible");
});
```

```css
header {
  height: 80px;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: right;
  top: 0;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
  transition: transform 0.6s, -webkit-transform 0.6s;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 500;
}

main {
  background-color: #485274;
  height: 100vh;
  padding-top: 80px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
  transform-origin: left center;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s 50ms;
  transition: transform 0.6s 50ms;
  transition: transform 0.6s 50ms, -webkit-transform 0.6s 50ms;
}

.nav-button {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  outline: none;
}

.nav-wrapper {
  background-color: ;
  box-shadow: -1px 0px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 80px;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
  transform: translateX(100%);
  transition: visibility 0.6s, -webkit-transform 0.6s;
  transition: transform 0.6s, visibility 0.6s;
  transition: transform 0.6s, visibility 0.6s, -webkit-transform 0.6s;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 25vw;
}

.nav-visible .nav-wrapper {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  transform: translateX(0);
  visibility: visible;
}

.nav {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  transform: rotateY(90deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
  transform-origin: left center;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
  transition: transform 0.6s, -webkit-transform 0.6s;
}

.nav-visible .nav {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

.nav li.active a {
  background-color: #212635;
}

.nav a {
  display: block;
  line-height: 1.4;
  padding: 0.7em 0.5em 0.7em 1.4em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav a:focus,
.nav a:hover {
  background-color: #2b3145;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-marker {
  background-color: currentColor;
  height: 2.8rem;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 80px;
  width: 3px;
}

.nav-marker:before {
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right-color: inherit;
  content: "";
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 3px;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 0;
}

.color-1 {
  color: deeppink;
}

.button-lines {
  margin-right: 20px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 50;
  background: #fbfbfb;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1rem 0.5rem;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.lines {
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 0.2rem;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 0.2rem;
  width: 2rem;
  position: relative;
}

.lines:after {
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 0.2rem;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 0.2rem;
  width: 0.9em;
  content: "";
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.lines:before {
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 0.2rem;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 0.2rem;
  width: 2rem;
  content: "";
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.lines:after {
  top: 0.5rem;
}

.lines:before {
  top: -0.5rem;
}

.button-lines-x .lines {
  transition: background .3s ease;
}

.button-lines-x .lines:after,
.button-lines-x .lines:before {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50% 0;
  transform-origin: 50% 50% 0;
  transition: top .3s .4s ease, -webkit-transform .3s ease;
  transition: top .3s .4s ease, transform .3s ease;
  transition: top .3s .4s ease, transform .3s ease, -webkit-transform .3s ease;
}

.nav-visible .button-lines-x .lines {
  background: #000;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.nav-visible .button-lines-x .lines:after {
  display: none;
  transition: top .3s ease, -webkit-transform .3s .3s ease;
  transition: top .3s ease, transform .3s .3s ease;
  transition: top .3s ease, transform .3s .3s ease, -webkit-transform .3s .3s ease;
}

.nav-visible .button-lines-x .lines:before {
  top: 0;
  transition: top .3s ease, -webkit-transform .3s .3s ease;
  transition: top .3s ease, transform .3s .3s ease;
  transition: top .3s ease, transform .3s .3s ease, -webkit-transform .3s .3s ease;
}

.nav-visible .button-lines-x .lines:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 45deg);
  transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 45deg);
  display: none;
}

.nav-visible .button-lines-x .lines:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-95deg);
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1 class="header-title">Bulbasaur</h1>
  <button aria-label='Toggle menu' class='nav-button button-lines button-lines-x close' role='button' type='button'>
     <span class='lines'></span>
   </button>

  <nav class='nav-wrapper'>
    <ul class='nav'>
      <li class='active'>
        <a href='#'>Page 1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href='#'>Page 2</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href='#'>Page 3</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href='#'>Page 4</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <span class='nav-marker color-1'></span>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: И подскажите пожалуйста в каких строках что вы изменили чтобы мне понять суть.

Comment: line-after   line-before я менял